# Obtain array result type, from PDO's query method

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

When We have `WHERE` condition in `SELECT` query, we can use PDO's prepare statement:

```
    $sth = $db->prepare("SELECT name FROM mytable WHERE id > :id");
    $sth->execute( array(":id"=>2) );
    $result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

So we obtain variable `$result` which type is `array`.

But when we dont have `WHERE` condition, we dont need prepare statement right? we use only `query`

```
$result = $db->query("SELECT name FROM books");
```

but now, `$result` type is not `array`, but `pdostatement`.

What is best way, for obtain also `array` types (and not `pdostatement`) in situations like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$result = $db->query("SELECT name FROM books")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

In other words, `$db->query()` does both `prepare()` and `execute()`